# How select `Only String` and `Only Int`

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, int, nvarchar

I have some `nvachar` data in a my database.

aaaa , bb1b, c+cc , 1234 , dser , 5896

I need to two select for `Only String` and `Only Int`. This is mean :

Result of first select be  : `aaaa` , `dser`

Result of second select be : `1234` , `5896`

How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`LIKE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) to perform this comparison. By using a double-negative, you can perform the tests with a single expression each:

```
declare @t table (val varchar(10) not null)
insert into @t(val)
select 'aaaa' union all
select 'bb1b' union all
select 'c+cc' union all
select '1234' union all
select 'dser' union all
select '5896'

select * from @t where val not like '%[^A-Z]%'
select * from @t where val not like '%[^0-9]%'
```

The first `select` says "give me all strings that **don't** contain a **non-alphabetic** character". Similarly, the second says "give me all strings that **don't** contain a **non-digit**"

Comment: That's what I was about to go with, but then I thought: `''` doesn't contain a non-alphabetic character, nor a non-digit.

Comment: @AndriyM - true, I did think of mentioning that. But the OP hasn't mentioned whether they need to deal with empty strings, nor what class they should fall into (if any). The above places the empty string in both classes.

Comment: You are right. Also, it is not that hard to add `and val <> ''` to the conditions (which might even turn out unnecessary if the real data are all 4-character strings, like in the examples). At the very least, yours is a good suggestion to start with.

Comment: Sadly, the `'%[^0-9]%'` expression doesn't work in SQLite.. since it doesn't support brackets and ranges..

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for a regular expression.

In your example the query would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE foo LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND foo NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM example WHERE foo NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%' AND foo LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
```

Maybe you have to do UPPERCASE(foo) for case insensitive checks. And add other characters like +, - and so on to the NOT LIKE expression.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489(SQL.90).aspx

Comment: NB: It's not a full regex, just a character range.